# How to show $\partial A = \varnothing \Rightarrow A=R^n$

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry

Let $A\subset R^n$ and dim$A=n$, $\partial A$ is the relative boundary of $A$. If $\partial A=\varnothing$ how to show $A$ is $R^n$ ?

Picture below is from XX page of  Schneider R.-Convex Bodies_ The Brunn-Minkowski Theory-Cambridge University Press (2013).

> [image]

Comment: $\partial A$ is the relative boundary of $A$ with respect to what subset?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli  respect to affine hull. I don't know there are different relative boundary, and have edit it again.

Comment: This is not true. Take $A$ to be any line. It is its own affine hull, so its boundary relative to it affine hull is empty. If the ambient space is of dimension larger than $1$, this gives a counterexample.

Comment: @lanse7pty Ah, the convex hull makes sense: perhaps it's the only case of actual use. I just googled and found a definition like: "if $A\subseteq B\subseteq X$, then the relative boundary of $A$ in $B$ is the boundary of $A$ in the subspace topology of $B$".

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez    Yes, if dim$A=n$, how to show it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\dim A=n$, then the relative boundary of course coincides with the usual boundary of $A$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Then $\mathbb R^n$ is the union of the interior of $A$ and the exterior of $A$, two open sets. As $\mathbb R^n$ is connected, one of the two is empty, and $A$ is not.